# Why this throw Null^2 Return[e1]?

Tags: functions

I am amazed by the difficulty of Mathematica, due to my OOP background. Why does the following code not return the output I am expecting?

```
ei[x_] :=Module[{e1 = {1,0,0},e2 = {0,1,0}, e3= {0,0,1}},

If[Mod[x,3]==0, Return[e1]]
If[Mod[x,3]==1, Return[e2]]
If[Mod[x,3]==2, Return[e3]]
];
```

**Input:**

```
ei[1]
```

I expected {0,1,0} to be returned; however, the returned result was:

```
Null^2 Return[e1]
```

Comment: If you evaluate `?CompoundExpression` you will have the answer. Your 3 `If` statements are being multiplied.

Comment: This might help to see the issue. `In[85]:= InputForm[DownValues[ei]]
Out[85]//InputForm=
{HoldPattern[ei[x_]] :> Module[{e1 = {1, 0, 0}, e2 = {0, 1, 0}, e3 = {0, 0, 1}}, If[Mod[x, 3] == 0, Return[e1]]*If[Mod[x, 3] == 1, Return[e2]]*
    If[Mod[x, 3] == 2, Return[e3]]]}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau oh, my gosh. There isn't more simple solution? My teacher will be shocked

Comment: It's just some missing semicolons.  The `If`s need to be separated by semicolons.  The newlines between this is interpreted as multiplication, like any whitespace would.  BTW the *last* semicolon after the function definition is not needed.  You can also consider replacing the whole thing with a `Which`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau sometimes I see how excellent and short Mathematica commands. But I wrote in Mathermatica like in C++

Comment: Shocked that you omitted semicolons? That would be an extreme reaction. (Or do you go to one of those really severe academies, where whenever a student makes a mistake the administration corporally punishes the instructor?)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I think that you give me a "hack". Or it is just for education purpose?

Comment: Sorry, really stupid fail.

Comment: The purpose of showing the `DownValues` in `InputForm` (I assume that's what you refer to) is that it then shows the explicit multiplication signs. If you don't see those it becomes more difficult to understand what you did incorrectly in the coding, and how to address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about to be closed and rightfully so, but while it's open...

This

```
ei[x_] :=Module[{e1 = {1,0,0},e2 = {0,1,0}, e3= {0,0,1}},

If[Mod[x,3]==0, Return[e1]]
If[Mod[x,3]==1, Return[e2]]
If[Mod[x,3]==2, Return[e3]]
];
```

is equivalent to this

```
ei[x_] :=Module[{e1 = {1,0,0},e2 = {0,1,0}, e3= {0,0,1}},

If[Mod[x,3]==0, Return[e1]] If[Mod[x,3]==1, Return[e2]] If[Mod[x,3]==2, Return[e3]]
];
```

which is equivalent to this

```
ei[x_] :=Module[{e1 = {1,0,0},e2 = {0,1,0}, e3= {0,0,1}},

If[Mod[x,3]==0, Return[e1]]*If[Mod[x,3]==1, Return[e2]]*If[Mod[x,3]==2, Return[e3]]
];
```

You should have wrote this (note the semicolons at the end of each line)

```
ei[x_] :=Module[{e1 = {1,0,0},e2 = {0,1,0}, e3= {0,0,1}},

If[Mod[x,3]==0, Return[e1]];
If[Mod[x,3]==1, Return[e2]];
If[Mod[x,3]==2, Return[e3]]
];
```